# How to delete multiply rows in a range that has criteria?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table that has row id's, i want to delete each row id with the same row id base on the price criteria.

I'm able to delete the rows but how would i delete if it was multiply

If price = 700, delete row Id's 3 and 4 in the whole range. I can delete the row that has the 700 but not sure how to delete the other row that has the same id's.

[image]

```
for i = 1 to 10
   if cells(i,3).value = 700 then
        cells(i,3).EntireRow.Delete
        'how to delete the other row that has the same row id?
   End if
next i
```

Comment: You also need to change your loop to work backwards, i.e. `For i = 10 To 1 Step -1`.

Comment: Are there different tracking numbers in your actual dataset, or are all values in ColA the same?

Comment: There's going to be multiply different tracking numbers with the same row ids 1,2,3,4,5 and i want to delete multiply rows that has 700 in different tracking number at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked in my small test:

```
Sub DeleteRows()

    Dim rng As Range, rw As Range, k, dict, x As Long
    Dim rngDelete As Range

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    'first pass - find all "duplicate" id's
    For x = 2 To rng.Rows.Count
        Set rw = rng.Rows(x)
        k = rw.Cells(1) & "~" & rw.Cells(2)
        If Application.CountIfs(rng.Columns(1), rw.Cells(1), _
                                rng.Columns(3), rw.Cells(3)) > 1 Then
            rw.Interior.Color = vbYellow '<<< for QC
            dict.Add k, True '<<remember this combination
        End If
    Next x
    'second pass - flag rows for deletion
    For x = 2 To rng.Rows.Count
        Set rw = rng.Rows(x)
        k = rw.Cells(1) & "~" & rw.Cells(2)
        If dict.exists(k) Then BuildRange rngDelete, rw
    Next x

    If Not rngDelete Is Nothing Then rngDelete.Delete

End Sub

Sub BuildRange(ByRef rngTot As Range, ByRef rngAdd As Range)
    If Not rngTot Is Nothing Then
        Set rngTot = Application.Union(rngTot, rngAdd)
    Else
        Set rngTot = rngAdd
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully something like this can be adapted for your needs:

```
Sub tgr()

    Const sIDCol As String = "B"
    Const sPriceCol As String = "C"

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rCheck As Range
    Dim rCheckCell As Range
    Dim rDel As Range

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rCheck = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, sPriceCol), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, sPriceCol).End(xlUp))

    For Each rCheckCell In rCheck.Cells                             'Loop through each cell in rCheck
        If rCheckCell.Value = 700 Then                              'If the cell = 700
            Select Case ws.Cells(rCheckCell.Row, sIDCol).Value
                Case 3, 4                                           'And the cell in column sIDCol in the same row = 3 or 4
                    If rDel Is Nothing Then                         'then add the cell to the rDel range
                        Set rDel = rCheckCell
                    Else
                        Set rDel = Union(rDel, rCheckCell)
                    End If

                Case Else
                    'Do nothing

            End Select
        End If
    Next rCheckCell

    If Not rDel Is Nothing Then rDel.EntireRow.Delete               'If there's anything in the rDel range, delete those rows

End Sub
```

Comment: i have multply tracking numbers, not sure if this will work for multiply tracking number.

Comment: @pokemon_Man Tracking number is not looked at per your description nor your attempted code.  This provided code will also ignore tracking number and it only looks at the Price to check if it's 700 and the Row ID to check if it's 3 or 4.  All rows matching that criteria, regardless of tracking number, will be deleted.  Are your requirements different?

Comment: Yes, my pic only show 1 set of tracking number but there are multiply and i need to delete lets say 700 from each different id number in each tracking number.

Comment: @pokemon_Man This provided code will already do that.  If you test it and it doesn't work as you need, please update your question with better sample data and expected results.